# How do I stop a leak / change the cartridge on this faucet handle?

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I recently moved into a new apartment and have a slow leak from the left faucet handle in the bathroom (given the build up you can see in the photo, it’s probably been leaking for a while). I assume I just need to change the cartridge but I can’t find the screw to release the handle so I can get access. I’ve unscrewed the hexagonal cover and pulled it up but there’s nothing there. I’ve also tried prying off the top cap (the ‘H’ in the photo) in case it’s under there but it sits absolutely flush so I can’t get any leverage to get it off. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: try unscrewing the handle (the horizontal part)

Comment: If it's an apartment, that typically means you're not the owner.  Under the assumption that you're renting, most repair type issues would be done by the landlord, at their expense, as part of maintaining the property to safe and habitable conditions.  At least in the USA.  Your lease agreement may have different terms, but unless you know you're responsible for plumbing repairs, it's best to let the landlord (or their designated maintenance person) deal with it for liability issues.  If you cause a leak and you're not supposed to be doing plumbing repairs, it will be on you to pay for damages.

Answer (score 1):

The H and C symbols ontop of the handle need to be pried off carefully and there is the screw that sets the handle.

Comment: .... where *carefully* may begin its life meaning "try not to scratch the handle" but then progress to "try not to cut your fingers or crack the counter" and eventually become "bash it in with a screwdriver and hammer hoping you can find a replacement on Amazon" but hopefully never progressing to "take your frustrations out on it with a sledgehammer".   This should literally be in the manual.